# Tracing back tripped require() to a source code line

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, evm, solc

What would be the process to map failed transactions (require, throw, etc.) back to the source code line where they occurred?

Any examples of such yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something you are looking for is here [How to map EVM trace to contract source?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25479/how-to-map-evm-trace-to-contract-source). As for me for development purposes I use `requireDebugModifier` from code below, for production I change `requireDebugModifier` to `requireModifier`.

```
contract DebugEvents
{
    event Debug(string message);

    modifier requireDebugModifier(bool arg, string message)
    {
        if (!arg)
        {
            Debug(message);
            return;
        }
        _;

    }

    modifier requireModifier(bool arg)
    {
        require(arg);
        _;
    }
}

contract Test is DebugEvents
{
    function Test() public payable
    {
    }

    function fooDevel(uint i)
    requireDebugModifier(i<10, "I must be less then 10")
    public
    returns (uint)
    {
        return i;
    }


    function fooProduction(uint i)
    requireModifier(i<10)
    public
    returns (uint)
    {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method only works if you modify the contract and thus not really answer to the question, because it deals with Solidity Events, not throws.

Comment: However the question you linked is currently the most useful source of information on this topic. As far as I can read the answer "no one has done it publicly." I'll grant you the bounty points any case, so that the good karma does not go unspend :)