# Is it possible to trace a function call hitting revert?

Tags: contract-debugging, evm, revert-opcode

It is possible to trace a transaction with [debug_traceTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction). But it needs the transaction hash, requiring it to be a transaction in first place.

I'm debugging a function call that generates a revert, and I want to recover the parameter passed in the revert opcode.

Comment: Might be little bit related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31434/tracing-back-tripped-require-to-a-source-code-line