# Solidity sourceMap and opcodes. No map entries for every code?

Tags: solidity, evm, contract-debugging, solc, opcode

After compiling a simple contract, the output are these values:

```
    "opcodes": "PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH1 0xF JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0xA1 DUP1 PUSH2 0x1E PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY PUSH1 0x0 RETURN STOP PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x4 CALLDATASIZE LT PUSH1 0x3F JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 CALLDATALOAD PUSH29 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SWAP1 DIV PUSH4 0xFFFFFFFF AND DUP1 PUSH4 0xCFAE3217 EQ PUSH1 0x44 JUMPI JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH1 0x4F JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x56 PUSH1 0x6C JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP3 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 PUSH1 0x1 SWAP1 POP SWAP1 JUMP STOP LOG1 PUSH6 0x627A7A723058 KECCAK256 0xda PUSH1 0x6B 0x48 NOT 0xdf PUSH29 0x26043B722E99B8A3CA14C3FE0E56FC2EF51FD2B8D9737230F300290000 ",

    "sourceMap": "24:101:0:-;;;;8:9:-1;5:2;;;30:1;27;20:12;5:2;24:101:0;;;;;;;"
```

How is it possible to have 21 references in the sourceMap (20 semicolons) for an opcode set of near 100 instructions? Shouldn't it be one sourceMap reference for one opcode? Thx for any help provided!

Ref.: [How to map EVM trace to contract source?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25479/how-to-map-evm-trace-to-contract-source)

Comment: According to https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/internals/source_mappings.html they should be, right?